# php ErrorHandler - Error Count

Tags: php, function, handler

As you probably already know, the error handler in php can be replaced by a function using

> set_error_handler()

I'm making my own error handler, and I want to do something when I have gotten all of the errors.

As of right now, the custom error handling function will be executed **every** time an error occurs.

So, what a way to know if it's the last error, so I can execute a html script.

Comment: until the script exits there is no way to know it is the last error so store previous data from the error handler and only output it as the last stage of your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function):

> Registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or
>   exit() is called.

But you'd better assure that your callback function does not trigger any error xD

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I had in mind, but it actually got the job dne, thanks a lot. Have struggled the whole day! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle all the errors in one go (which means you will lose visibility of errors occuring before a fatal error - hence I do not recomend this) then register a sutdown function and just accumulate the data via your error handler then in your shutdown function report the errors....

```
<?php

$mylog="started\n"

function logit() {
    global $mylog;
    if ($mylog) {
       file_put_contents(tmpnam('/var/log/php', 'err');
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('logit');
function whoops()
{
    global $mylog;
    $mylog.="something bad happenned\n";
}
set_error_handler('whoops');
....
```

(this can all be done with an auto-prepend file)